# How can I unlock the lock screen of my RealMe 9 Pro Plus without formatting device, or retrieve just the storage?

Tags: security, lock-screens, data-recovery, locked-out

I haven't been able to unlock my Realme 9 Pro Plus phone with the passwords that I remember. And I'm not sure what to do next.

I have always found it a bugging issue when my Realme phone asks me to enter my lock screen password every 72 hours so I don't forget it. I mostly use my fingerprint unlock, but when the mentioned message comes up, I have to enter my password every time.

Although it's a measure to prevent someone from forgetting passwords, unfortunately it became the reason I'm locked out of my phone. I have always put it right, over many months, but this time its not right.

My phone storage is sort of precious to me, about 126-127 GB out of 128 GB is at use, contains lots of media and other things that I made over life. (Including, being transferred from other old Realme phone, so its data of over 2 years I suppose.) I want the data to be safe.

I do not have expert tech repair offices here. Most know how to format/hard reset a phone when screenlock cant be bypassed. But I remember seeing a video on Instagram where some professional did some storage retrieval on a broken phone's encrypted storage, or something of that sort, and I'm even willing to keep the phone for years, locked, in hope someday I'll get to unlock it thru somebody, or storage retrieved.

With that said, I'm willing to do necessary steps to retrieve storage or unlock the phone, as much as I can.

Please do note that USB debugging is not enabled. I would have always kept it enabled for my convenience, but this phone sends a notification every 2-3 days I guess, saying Dev options is turned on and suggests to turn off. It bugged me every now and then as a regular user and hence I turned USB debugging off when it was no longer of use.

Please guide me what I should do. I'm also willing to root the phone if needed. And as I said I'm not willing to lose data on it. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you rebooted the phone? Because if yes your "enemy" is not the lock screen but the device encryption. After every reboot the entered lock screen password is transmitted to the Android Gatekeeper which uses it to provide the user data encryption key. Without that key the data remains encrypted and to my knowledge there is no way to get the key but through Gatekeeper (which means no password means no data). Even if you have had enabled adb, then access to user data would have been blocked in such a case.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Although, the locked phone issue had been since two weeks or so, and the phone has been rebooted multiple times..

Comment: Then the only way to get your data is entering the correct PIN/password.